# Cross-Origin Read Blocking Error while using Ajax get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need te execute an Ajax get method when I click on a button, Here is my code :

```
 $.ajax({         
        url: "https://myapi/",           
        headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        type: "GET",
        data:{key:'***', schema:'***', table:'***',where_clause:'0', liste_fields:'*'}, 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            console.log("---")
            console.log(result)
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }

        });
```

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://myapi/?callback=jQuery3410379708076493414_1586162966175&key=***&schema=***&table=***&where_clause=0&liste_fields=*&_=1586162966176 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

How can I fix this problem and have the result of my request (200) and the data I'm requesting?
Thank you

Comment: The `Access-Control-X` headers need to be placed in the response generated by your *server*, not the in request coming from the client.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Where should I add this line?

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to answer that. There are lots of CORS guides already if you research. For example, if your API is written in PHP research 'PHP enable CORS'